# Ошибка загрузки текстуры sfml

Tags: c++, sfml

Пытаюсь загрузить текстуру следующим образом:

```
...
Texture texture_Grass;
texture_Grass.loadFromFile("grass.png");
...
```

В консоли выдает ошибку:

```
Failed to load image " Юо m☺grass.png   ☼sУ▲H√⌂            oY"H√C8H√⌂йКэ┤Ў⌂". Reason: Unable to open file
```

Сама текстура находится в том же каталоге, где и main.cpp. Проверил через fstream, файл виден.
Такая проблема только с текстурами, какие-либо другие тестовые программы (отображение геометрических фигур, изменение цвета объектов) работают.

Comment: Похоже на проблему с символами в пути к файлу. Попробуйте переместить файл в директорию с названием, состоящим только из латинских символов, если сейчас это не так.

Comment: Используйте абсолютные пути к файлам.

Comment: @tocic Путь до проекта содержит только латинский символы

Comment: @user7860670 Попробовал написать texture_Grass.loadFromFile("D:/documents/VS_Projects/games/test/grass.png");
Выводит: Failed to load image "". Reason: Unable to open file
Я так понимаю, что в этом случае файл вообще не виден.

Comment: Нет, это значит, что файл не открывается по другой причине, а не из-за кривого относительного пути. Возможно попытка загрузить текстуру происходит до создания окна рендера или что-то подобное.

Comment: на всякий случай: классы SFML в большинстве своём не предназначены для создания, как static или extern, если такие есть, то лучше уберите

Answer (score 0):

Помогла переустановка sfml в проект